# <ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain error on a scope that was working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been running a piece of code for a while with success but it has just started throwing an error - we've altered the way data is going into the database but believe it's more likely a programming issue or I've altered it by mistake, but can't see where.

The issue appears to be caused form a scope, we're running Rails 4.2.2

The complete error is

```
undefined method `call' for 
 ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x007feb8f5c49f0> Did you mean? caller

app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:158:in `weekly_sales_report'
```

in my orders_controller line 158

```
@sales_this_week_bysales = Order.select("COUNT(order_id) AS nosales, AVG(net_amount) AS avgsale,SUM(sale_cost) AS sale_cost, SUM(net_amount) AS weeklysalestotal, owner_id AS salesman").sales.where.(date_of_sale: (@startdate .. @enddate)).with_salesman.group(:owner_id)
```

in my orders.rb model I have the following used scopes

```
scope :with_salesman, -> { joins(:pipe_records).where(pipe_records: {pipe_part_id: 1}).where.not(pipe_records: {owner_id: nil}) }

scope :sales, -> {where ("orders.order_ref <>'' and date_of_sale IS NOT NULL ")}
```

I re-wrote the scope to the below but still got the same error

```
scope :with_salesman, -> { joins(" INNER JOIN pipe_records ON pipe_records.order_id = orders.id WHERE pipe_records.pipe_part_id =1 AND pipe_records.owner_id <>'' ") }
```

I also removed the WHERE startdate criteria from the sales.where on 158 which returned a different error, but it appears the scope isn't passing correctly anymore or returning an error due to bad records??

I'm now unsure what is happening, I went back to my remotes and took a copy of the code from a couple of days ago and this also threw the same error, but it was working correctly. We've put a lot of new records in recently through a new form which bypasses and alters created at dates which may be to blame. I would appreciate any suggestions or fresh eyes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the period between `where` and the parenthesis.

```
where.(date_of_sale: (@startdate..@enddate))
```

In `ruby`

```
receiver.()
```

is short hand for  `receiver.call()` thus the error you are receiving

Comment: worlds largest facepalm.... 
Had looked at it a hundred times and missed that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to remove that period after `where`:

```
where.(date_of_sale: (@startdate .. @enddate))
```